# What's wrong with this youtube-dl automatic script?

Tags: bash, variables, youtube-dl

first of all, I'm quite new with bash scripting and I'm just starting to learn, evidently there's something wrong with this script, but I don't know what it is...

I created a bash script to automate downloading videos with youtube-dl:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo url:
read url
export url
youtube-dl -f 'bestvideo[height<=360]+worstaudio/worst[height<=360]' $url
```

The idea is that I type in the command line the name of the script, e.g.: "360" and it will ask for a url (e.g.: a Youtube video), I paste it and youtube-dl downloads it with the stated parameters. It works like a charm...

Now, I want to make the script more complex and I think I need to convert the youtube-dl command to a variable (of course, being a newbie, I might be wrong, but let's assume I'm right for a moment...)

```
#!/bin/bash

video="youtube-dl -f 'bestvideo[height<=360]+worstaudio/worst[height<=360]'"

echo url:
read url
export url
$video $url
```

When I try this, it throws me an error: "ERROR: requested format not available
"
I don't know what's wrong... I'd like to solve the problem with the least changes to the code as possible and I repeat, I'd like to know what's wrong with the current code so I can learn from it.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Side note: you don't need to `export url` - it doesn't add anything here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's explained in detail here here: [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

First **always** double-quote your variables, unless you know *exactly* what will happen if you don't.

You don't need to `export` that variable: you're not invoking any other program that needs to use it.

When you want to re-use a command, think about putting it in a function:

```
#!/bin/bash
function video {
    youtube-dl -f 'bestvideo[height<=360]+worstaudio/worst[height<=360]' "$1"
}
read -p "url: " url
video "$url"
```

Actually, I would do this:

1. add that function to your ~/.bashrc,
2. source that file: `source ~/.bashrc`
3. then you can use it from the command line:

   ```
   video 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ'
   ```

Comment: Fantastic, it works perfect with several combinations of parameters!... As I said, I'm just beginning to learn bash script and I understand like 10% of what I see on Internet when I search for help... One question about your code modifications, though... Why exactly is needed the "$1" ?

Comment: That represents the first argument you provide for the function. In this case that is how the function receives `"$url"`

Comment: You could also change `"$1"` to `"$@"` so that you can call it like `video url1 url2 url3 ...`

Comment: Great, now I understand!... Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the single quote from the -f parameter it will work.

For eg.

```
video="youtube-dl -f bestvideo[height<=360]+worstaudio/worst[height<=360]"
```